# SSRS report server DB connection setup with Sybase

Tags: reporting-services, sybase

I am trying to configure Sybase 15 database connection details in the new windows SSRS server as follows. But getting error "**Specified method is not supported.**" which I click on test connection in SSRS.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXbHJ.png)

OLE DB:

Connection string: Server=xyz.com;Provider=ASEOLEDB;Port=5000;

entered username and password as given in the screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10lvF.png)

ODBC:

Connection string: driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise;Server=xyz.com;Port=5000;

entered username and password as given in the screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amfrH.png)

Followed below micro soft link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/sybase/connect-to-sybase-sybasetosql?view=sql-server-ver16

- Please how to resolve **Specified method is not supported** error from SSRS.